# Solving Coupled partial differential equations of stiff nature using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to solve coupled partial differential equations of first order, which are of stiff nature. I have coded in MATLAB to solve this pde's, I have used Method of line to convert PDE into ODE, and i have used beam and warmings(second order upwind) method to discritize the spatial derivative. The discretization method is total variation diminishing(TVD) to eliminate the oscillation. But rather using TVD and ode15s solver to integrate resultant stiff ode's the resultant plot is oscillatory(not smooth). What should i do to eliminate this oscillation and get correct results.

I have attached my MATLAB code.. please see it and suggest some improvement.

```
∂y(1)/∂t=-0.1 ∂y(1)/∂x + (0.5*e^(15*(y(2)⁄(1+y(2))))*(1- y(1))

∂y(2)/∂t=-0.1 ∂y(2)/∂x - (0.4*e^(15*(y(2)⁄(1+y(2))))*(1- y(1))-0.4

Initial condition:  at  t = 0         y(1)= y(2)=0
Boundary condition:               y(1)= y(2) = 0              at   x=0
```

I have attached my MATLAB code.. please see it and suggest some improvement.

```
function brussode(N)

if nargin<1
    N = 149;
end

tspan = [0 10];
m = 0.00035
t = (1:N)/(N+1)*m;
y0 = [repmat(0,1,N); repmat(0,1,N)];
p = 0.5
q = 0.4

options = odeset('Vectorized','on','JPattern',jpattern(N));

[t,y] = ode15s(@f,tspan,y0,options);

a = size(y,2)
u = y(:,1:2:end);
x = (1:N)/(N+1);
figure;
%surf(x,t(end,:),u);
plot(x,u(end,:))
xlabel('space');
ylabel('solution');
zlabel('solution u');

%--------------------------------------------------------------
%Nested function -- N is provided by the outer function.
%
    function dydt = f(t,y)
        %Derivative function

        dydt = zeros(2*N,size(y,2));    %preallocate dy/dt

        x = (1:N)/(N+1);
        % Evaluate the 2 components of the function at one edge of the grid
        % (with edge conditions).
        i = 1;
        %y(1,:) = 0;
        %y(2,:) = 0;
        dydt(i,:) = -0.1*(N+1)*(y(i+2,:)-0)+ (0.01/2)*m*((N+1).^3)*(y(i+2,:)-0) + p*exp(15*(0/(1+0)))*(1-0);
        dydt(i+1,:) = -0.1*(N+1)*(y(i+3,:)-0)+ (0.01/2)*m*((N+1).^3)*(y(i+3,:)-0) - q*exp(15*(0/(1+0)))*(1-0)+0.25;


        i = 3;
        %y(1,:) = 0;
        %y(2,:) = 0;
        dydt(i,:) = -0.1*(N+1)*(y(i+2,:)-y(i,:)) + (0.01/2)*m*((N+1).^3)*(y(i+3,:)-y(i,:)) + p*exp(15*(y(i+1,:)/(1+y(i+1,:))))*(1-y(i,:));
        dydt(i+1,:) = -0.1*(N+1)*(y(i+3,:)-y(i+1,:)) + (0.01/2)*m*((N+1).^3)*(y(i+3,:)-y(i,:)) - q*exp(15*(y(i+1,:)/(1+y(i+1,:))))*(1-y(i,:))+0.25;


        %Evaluate the 2 components of the function at all interior grid
        %points.
        i = 5:2:2*N;
        %y(1,:) = 0;
       % y(2,:) = 0;
        dydt(i,:) = (-0.1/2)*(N+1)*(3*y(i,:)-4*y(i-2,:)+y(i-4,:)) +(0.01/2)*m*((N+1).^3)*(y(i,:)-2*y(i-2,:)+y(i-4,:))+ p*exp(15*(y(i+1,:)/(1+y(i+1,:))))*(1-y(i,:));
        dydt(i+1,:) = (-0.1/2)*(N+1)*(3*y(i+1,:)-4*y(i-1,:)+y(i-3,:))+(0.01/2)*m*((N+1).^3)*(y(i+1,:)-2*y(i-1,:)+y(i-3,:)) - q*exp(15*(y(i+1,:)/(1+y(i+1,:))))*(1-y(i,:))+0.25;


    end
%-------------------------------------------------------------

end  %brussode

%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Subfunction -- the sparsity pattern
%

function S = jpattern(N)
% Jacobian sparsity patter
B = ones(2*N,5);
B(2:2:2*N,2) = zeros(N,1);
B(1:2:2*N-1,4) = zeros(N,1);
S = spdiags(B,-2:2,2*N,2*N);
end
%-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This sounds to me like a question about math more than a question about coding. I suggest you flag this question using a custom moderator flag, and have it moved to [math.se] or perhaps even [scicomp.se].

Comment: No.. its an coding oriented question.